# regex to get some JSON inside test

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have some texts formatted in this way:

```
var string = 'some random text fjijd {"Type":"NewTunnel","Payload":{"ReqId":"e425ebb50d220816","Url":"asaa","Protocol":"http","Error":""}} some other text bla bla'
```

I am wondering how can i extract the json stringified object that can be parsed then with a regex.

## Update

I am running a sub process from node.js application using `spawn` and the `stdout` data (that is application log `-log=stdout`) in plain text formatted in this way. Don't ask me how and why, sorry!

```
var cproc = require("child_process");
proc = cproc.spawn("./ngrok", ['-log=stdout', '8080']);
proc.stdout.on("data", function(res) {
  console.log("Data received: " + res);
});
```

Data received is plain text, something like this:

```
[08/10/14 01:49:37] [DEBG] [ctl:604a481c] Read message {"Type":"ReqProxy","Payload":{}}
```

It includes also debugging infos!

Comment: Why is the string invalid JSON to begin with?

Comment: ({.*}) if there are no curly brackets in the random text

Comment: The real question is, why do you have some text padding around your JSON?

Comment: I am running a sub process from nodejs application using spawn and the stdout data (that is application log (-log=stdout)) is plain text formatted in this way. don't ask me how and why, sorry!

`var cproc = require("child_process");

proc = cproc.spawn("./ngrok", ['-log=stdout', '8080']);

proc.stdout.on("data", function(res) { 
        console.log("Data received: " + res);
});`

Data received is plain text, something like this:
Data received: `[08/10/14 01:49:37] [DEBG] [ctl:604a481c] Read message {"Type":"ReqProxy","Payload":{}}`
It includes also debugging infos! 

 @plalx @mscdex

Comment: @Morrisda if you want to include new code, it's best to edit your question instead of writing comment.

Comment: i was just answering to plalx !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last update: yet another solution

```
/((?:{).*(?:}))/g
```

---

The initial answer:

What about this. I believe you need only the JSON part within this string. If you don't expect nested object the pattern could be changed to `/({.*?})/g`

```
var s = 'some random text fjijd {"Type":"NewTunnel","Payload":{"ReqId":"e425ebb50d220816","Url":"asaa","Protocol":"http","Error":""}} some other text bla bla';
var m = s.match(/({.*})/g);  // or /({+.*}+)/g  or /(({+).*(}+))/g
console.log(m[0]);
```

Output:

```
{"Type":"NewTunnel","Payload":{"ReqId":"e425ebb50d220816","Url":"asaa","Protocol":"http","Error":""}}
```

[Demo1](http://regex101.com/r/hC8kS2/3) | [Demo2](http://regex101.com/r/hC8kS2/4)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
({.*})
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/tE2kB0/2)**

[image]